# Issues with retain cycle using AsyncStream in a Task

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, task, asyncstream

Found this issue while working with the new Swift concurrency tools.

Here's the setup:

```
class FailedDeinit {
    
    init() {
        print(#function, id)
        task = Task {
            await subscribe()
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        print(#function, id)
    }
    
    func subscribe() async {
        let stream = AsyncStream<Double> { _ in }
        for await p in stream {
            print("\(p)")
        }
    }
    
    private var task: Task<(), Swift.Error>?
    let id = UUID()
}

var instance: FailedDeinit? = FailedDeinit()
instance = nil
```

Running this code in a Playground yields this:

`init() F007863C-9187-4591-A4F4-BC6BC990A935`

!!! The `deinit` method is never called!!!

Strangely, when I change the code to this:

```
class SuccessDeinit {
    
    init() {
        print(#function, id)
        task = Task {
            let stream = AsyncStream<Double> { _ in }
            for await p in stream {
                print("\(p)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        print(#function, id)
    }
    
    private var task: Task<(), Swift.Error>?
    let id = UUID()
}

var instance: SuccessDeinit? = SuccessDeinit()
instance = nil
```

By moving the code from the method `subscribe()` directly in the Task, the result in the console changes to this:

```
init() 0C455201-89AE-4D7A-90F8-D6B2D93493B1
deinit 0C455201-89AE-4D7A-90F8-D6B2D93493B1
```

This may be a bug or not but there is definitely something that I do not understand. I would welcome any insight about that.

~!~!~!~!

This is crazy (or maybe I am?) but with a SwiftUI macOS project. I still DON'T get the same behaviour as you. Look at that code where I kept the same definition of the `FailedDeinit` and `SuccessDeinit`  classes but used them within a SwiftUI view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var failed: FailedDeinit?
    @State private var success: SuccessDeinit?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button("Add failed") { failed = .init() }
                Button("Remove failed") { failed = nil }
            }
            HStack {
                Button("Add Success") { success = .init() }
                Button("Remove Success") { success = nil }
            }
        }
    }
}


class FailedDeinit {
    
    init() {
        print(#function, id)
        task = Task { [weak self] in
            await self?.subscribe()
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        print(#function, id)
    }
    
    func subscribe() async {
        let stream = AsyncStream<Double> { _ in }
        for await p in stream {
            print("\(p)")
        }
    }
    
    private var task: Task<(), Swift.Error>?
    let id = UUID()
}
```

Comment: This sounds interesting, but please do the test in a real app, not a playground, because playgrounds do not correctly emulate memory management (or async/await, for that matter).

Comment: I first stumbled on this issue while working in a real macOS app but trying to find the solution to the problem in this environment wasn't practical.

Comment: But by revealing suddenly that this all was happening in a State variable of SwiftUI project, you've totally moved the goalposts. That's not fair. I answered the question you _actually asked_. It's your own doing that you didn't ask the question you really wanted to know the answer to.

Comment: Oh my... I didn't mean to be offensive or anything like that. It's just that sometimes, framing the question is not as easy as it seems. In all honesty, the real problem was present in a class with nothing special and no SwiftUI was involved. That class and the rest of the app being very complex, I tried to isolate the issue by working in a playground and since the result was the same, I never suspected the playground. Following that and still wanting to keep the issue isolated, I built a small SwiftUI app to test your idea and merely reported that the issue was still not solved.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the following:

```swift
task = Task {
    await subscribe()
}
```

It is true that introduces a strong reference to `self`. You can resolve that strong reference with:

```swift
task = Task { [weak self] in
    await self?.subscribe()
}
```

But that is only part of the problem here. This `[weak self]` pattern only helps us in this case if either the `Task` has not yet started or if it has finished.

The issue is that as soon as `subscribe` starts executing, despite the `weak` reference in the closure, it will keep a strong reference to `self` until `subscribe` finishes. So, this `weak` reference is prudent, but it is not the whole story.

The issue here is more subtle than appears at first glance. Consider the following:

```swift
func subscribe() async {
    let stream = AsyncStream<Double> { _ in }
    for await p in stream {
        print("\(p)")
    }
}
```

The `subscribe` method will keep executing until the stream calls `finish`. But you never `finish` the `stream`. (You don’t `yield` any values, either. Lol.) Anyway, without anything in the `AsyncStream`, once `subscribe` starts it will never complete and thus will never release `self`.

So let us consider your second rendition, when you create the `Task`, bypassing `subscribe`:

```swift
task = Task {
    let stream = AsyncStream<Double> { _ in }
    for await p in stream {
        print("\(p)")
    }
}
```

Yes, you will see the object be deallocated, but you are neglecting to notice that this `Task` will never finish, either! So, do not be lulled into into a false sense of security just because the containing object was released: The `Task` never finishes! The memory associated with that `Task` will never get released (even if the parent object, `FailedDeinit` in your example, is).

This all can be illustrated by changing your stream to actually yield values and eventually `finish`:

```swift
task = Task {
    let stream = AsyncStream<Double> { continuation in
        Task {
            for i in 0 ..< 10 {
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1 * NSEC_PER_SECOND)
                continuation.yield(Double(i))
            }
            continuation.finish()
        }
    }

    for await p in stream {
        print("\(p)")
    }

    print("all done")
}
```

In this case, if you dismiss it while the stream is underway, you will see that the `AsyncStream` continues until it finishes. (And, if you happen to be doing this inside a method, the object in question will also be retained until the task is canceled.)

So, what you need to do is to `cancel` the `Task` if you want the `AsyncStream` to finish. And you also should implement `onTermination` of the continuation in such a manner that it stops the asynchronous stream.

But, the result is that if I `cancel` this when the view controller (or whatever) is released, then my example yielding values 0 through 9 will stop and the task will be freed.

It all comes down to what your `AsyncStream` is really doing. But in the process of simplifying the MCVE and removing the contents of the `AsyncStream`, you simultaneously do not handle cancelation and never call `finish`. Those two, combined, manifest the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really have anything to do with async/await or AsyncStream. It's a perfectly normal retain cycle. You (the FailedDeinit instance) are retaining the task, but the task refers to `subscribe` which is a method of you, i.e. `self`, so the task is retaining you. So simply break the retain cycle just like you would break any other retain cycle. Just change

```
    task = Task {
        await subscribe()
    }
```

To

```
    task = Task { [weak self] in
        await self?.subscribe()
    }
```

Also, be sure to test in a real project, not a playground, as playgrounds are not indicative of anything in this regard. Here's the code I used:

```
import UIKit

class FailedDeinit {

    init() {
        print(#function, id)
        task = Task { [weak self] in
            await self?.subscribe()
        }
    }

    deinit {
        print(#function, id)
    }

    func subscribe() async {
        let stream = AsyncStream<Double> { _ in }
        for await p in stream {
            print("\(p)")
        }
    }

    private var task: Task<(), Swift.Error>?
    let id = UUID()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var instance: FailedDeinit? = FailedDeinit()
        instance = nil
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! I just tried your proposition and (unfortunately),  it didn't change the result. The ```deinit``` is still not called.

Comment: Try it in a real project, though, not in a playground. That's where I tested. Playgrounds are not indicative of anything in this regard. — I'll add the actual code I used.